# Items are not populated in the list view

Tags: android, android-listview

This is layout xml

```
           <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/titleListView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </ListView>
```

My activity is:

```
public class DummyActivity extends Activity {

private ListView titleListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_assignment);

    titleListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.titleListView);

    showAssignmentTitlesInList();
}



private void showAssignmentTitlesInList()
{

    String[] monthsArray = { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY",
             "AUG", "SEPT", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DummyActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,monthsArray);
            titleListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.d("TAG", monthsArray.length+"");
}
}
```

This is my array Array adapter code...

I have one array of string called "Months array" and i need to show this as a list view.

Comment: Are you instantiating `titleListView`? Something like `titListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.titleListView);`

Comment: here it seems fine, where are you calling that code, is it reachable?

Comment: post your code where you initialize your listview

Comment: I guess you have not initialized you listview `ListView titleListView = (ListView)findviewById(R.id.titleListView)`

Comment: Sometimes if both the background color and font color are white, you can't see the list. Make sure its not the case.

Comment: where is your ListView in layout(activity_assignment) or different xml

Comment: my ListView is in activity_assignment only -shakeeb shaheen

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, monthsArray);
                titleListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

TRY THIS :

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(//// Your Activity Name.this /////,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, monthsArray);
                titleListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also initialize ListView in onCreate, if you haven't.

You can use BaseAdapter. It looks complex, but once you understand it, it's easy to implement